# how to read a table from oracle database in c++ codeblocks? I

Tags: c++, database, oracle, codeblocks

I have tried the the following code. It crashes on con.Connect statement. It gives segmentation fault. I am using oracle 11g xpress edition

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <SQLAPI.h>  

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    SAConnection con;
    try
    {
        con.Connect ("xe", "u1", "p1",SA_Oracle_Client);//con.Connect ("database name", "user name", "p",SA_Oracle_Client);
        printf("We are connected!\n");
        con.Disconnect();
        printf("We are disconnected!\n");
    }

    catch(SAException & x)
    {

        try
        {

            con.Rollback ();
        }
        catch(SAException &)
        {
        }

        printf("%s\n", (const char*)x.ErrText());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should the database name be in uppercase to match the ORACLE_SID ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add directory of Oracle C/C++ libraries to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. In my case, it is:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: I did not understand @Ali . I  have added oracle c/c++ libraires in codeblocks compiler setting. Can you please explain?I have used the following tutorial

Comment: I have used the following tutorial : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/database-connectivity-using-cc/